# how to skip action on first value returned from a regex search?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, append, iteration, beautifulsoup

the following:

- searches contents for spans of class blue
- grabs the text from the spans (using beautiful soup's get_text method)
- outputs the values on lines
- for each line, replaces some text
- does a regex search on each line
- appends the matched values to an empty list

**code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
the_list = []
spans = content.find_all('span', {'class' : 'blue'})
lines = [span.get_text() for span in spans]
for line in lines:
  line = line.replace(',','').replace(' am', 'am').replace(' pm','pm')
  m = re.search(r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d+:\d+[a|p]m)', line)
  if m:
    the_list.append(m.group(1))
```

i'd like to be able to skip appending the first result to the list.

so i tried:

```
for n, _ in enumerate(m):
  if n!=0:
    if m:
      the_list.append(m.group(1))
```

but i can't iterate over values in 'm', it gives error:

`TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object is not iterable`

**update/solution:**

it would be great to have a solution for future reference, but what i did was find a way to eliminate the unwanted value from the list prior to the above code block (just by creating a new list and filtering the values with `if x not in`) eg:

```
new_list = []
for i in old_list:
    if 'unique text' not in i:
        new_list.append(i)
for line in new_list:
.... etc as above
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with

```
regex = r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d+:\d+[a|p]m)'
your_regex.findall(line)
```

instead of

```
re.search
```

?

It should return a list